# Find missing words in rows in Notepad++

Tags: find, notepad++, missing-data, cpu-word

I have a folder with 2 kind of sentences/rows. One that has `< h1 >` tag, and other doesn't. Like so:

```
< td class="articles">Mama< /td>
< td class="articles">< h1>Tata < /h1>< /td>
```

I want to find with Notepad++ only the rows that doesn't have the word `< h1>`

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I find a simple solution, with notepad++ or with TextCrawler (or other text editor) First Search "h1" in all files. Export the results in a file_1.txt Then search "< td class="articles">" in all files. Export the results in a file_2.txt  Then open both document with notepad++ and use "Compare" plugin. You will see the difference. You will see underline the files that does't have "h1" Works. Just Test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the find or replace window (ctrl+f) or (ctrl+h) and set it to use regular expressions.

Now use the regex:

`(?-s)(?i)^(?:.(?!<(?: |\t)h1(?: |\t|>)))*$`

This will find any line that doesn't contain for example:

- `< h1 >`
- `<h1 style="">`
- `<H1    >`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Mark functionality (tab in the find window.) Make sure bookmark line is checked and search for 'h1'. The lines that are not bookmarked are the lines without a h1.

Comment: yes, but I want to find in 800 files this error, not just in one single document

Comment: Then open them and search. Or perhaps Notepad++ isn't the appropriate tool for this. Have you considered grep?

Comment: don't know about grep. I using windows 7. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Find All In Current Document" option with negative regex match operator: !